# Python - Get text after string and between brackets

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have an output that I am trying to parse. It is not exactly JSON so parsing via JSON is not working. Here is a snippet of the output

```
...    
"details": {
        "groups": [
          "group1",
          "group2",
          "group3",
          "group4"
        ]
      },
      "all_Details": [
        "ALL"
      ],
...
```

What I am trying to do is get the output after "groups" and between the []. So I want to parse out:

["group1","group2","group3","group4"]

Not the best with regex so wanted to see how I would go about parsing this out. Thanks.

Update:

Trying to parse via JSON. Here is the JSON output:

```
{
  "details": {
    "groups": [
        "group1",
        "group2",
        "group3",
      ]
  },
  "team": "team1",
  "createdat": "2017-08-11",
  "owningteam": "team2",
}
```

Here is what I have in Python:

```
parsed_json = json.loads(output)
print(parsed_json['details']['groups])
```

And I am getting the following error:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Please post your complete data structure. Does it have any regular structure? Could it be arbitrary?

Comment: dict['groups'].items()[0] ?

Comment: It sure looks like JSON, can you show us some not-JSON?

Comment: Please make an attempt with regex. We're not here to write basic code for you.

Comment: `"details"\s*:\s*\{\s*"groups"\s*:\s*(\[[\s\S]*?\])`?

Comment: @AlexHall Trying to use JSON parsing and added my attempts and the error I am getting to the original post.

Comment: If it gets past json.loads, it's valid JSON. However: (1) the data you posted throws an error on json.loads because of trailing commas (2) the code has a syntax error because it's missing a quote and (3) once these issues are fixed everything works fine, and the error you gave never happens. Please copy paste correctly and provide a [mcve] or we can't help you.

Comment: @AlexHall Thanks, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you posted is a string, it looks like it could just be evaluated as a python object like so:

```
import ast
d = ast.literal_eval('{"details": { "groups": [ "group1", "group2", "group3", "group4" ] }, "all_Details": [ "ALL" ]}')
```

Then to get what you want you can just do this:

```
d['details']['groups']
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want the output value between brackets of `groups` value like :

```
"group1","group2","group3","group4"
```

you can do like this:

```
data = ", ".join( repr(e) for e in groups ),
```

Here groups is a value of json data.